# Widget becomes invisible after reinstall

Tags: android, widget

I have a widget with configure activity. When the user wants to place the widget on the home screen, the configure activity opens, the user selects the content, background color and textcolor of the widget and there is it. When I reinstall the app, the widget becomes invisible. It is still there, but with no text and color. See img:
[image]

I am going to post all my files, and at the end, I will tell you what may be the problem. What I do not know is the solution.

**widgetconfigure.xml**

This is the layout of the configuration acitivty. I am not going to post this xml. It has textviews in layouts.

**widget_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="72dip"
    android:layout_height="72dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/widgetlayout">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
     android:layout_width="72dip" 
     android:layout_height="72dip"
     android:scaleType="fitXY">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvConfigInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dip"   
        android:textSize="12dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Part of the manifest where I register my configuration activity and the appwidgetprovider:**

```
   <activity
            android:name=".WidgetConfig"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".MyWidgetProvider" android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"></action>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget_info"></meta-data>
        </receiver>
```

**xml/widget_info.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:minWidth="72dp"
    android:configure="com.b2creative.notepad.WidgetConfig"> 
</appwidget-provider>
```

**WidgetConfig.java**

This is the configuration activity. The user selects the background and textcolor of the widget and the text from a listview to appear on the widget. I am going to post only the relevant part:

```
     AppWidgetManager awm;
        int awID;
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
        if (extras != null)
        {
            awID = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        }
        else
        {
            finish();
        }
        awm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(c);


//the code from here is in a button onclicklistener that sets the widget.

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvConfigInput, widgettext);
            views.setTextColor(R.id.tvConfigInput, loadedtextcolor);
            views.setFloat(R.id.tvConfigInput, "setTextSize", int_widgetfontsize);

            Paint p = new Paint(); 
            p.setAntiAlias(true);
            p.setStyle(Style.FILL);
            p.setColor(loadedbgcolor);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(GetDipsFromPixel(72), GetDipsFromPixel(72), Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, GetDipsFromPixel(72), GetDipsFromPixel(72));
            canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, 10, 10, p);
            views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.ImageView01, bitmap);
            Intent in = new Intent(c, Notepad.class);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, 0, in, 0);

            Intent result = new Intent();
            result.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, awID);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, result);

            awm.updateAppWidget(awID, views);

            finish();
```

**MyWidgetProvider.java**

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

        @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {

        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            int awID = appWidgetIds[i];
            RemoteViews v = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            //v.setTextViewText(R.id.tvConfigInput, "Something");
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(awID, v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
    }

}
```

So I am pretty sure the problem is here in the onUpdate method, as I am not setting the layout of the widget. I left a line with // to show if I add it, I get a widget with no background but with the text "Something".

How am I supposed to set the background color, the textcolor of the widget and the text of the TextView on the widget in this method? I don't know them, the user sets them when adding the widget. Or what am I supposed to do?

**EDIT**

I have found [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/appwidget/ExampleAppWidgetConfigure.html) code and modified mine like this:

I added 
    `saveTitlePref(this, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID, widgettext);` to the onClick method in the WidgetConfig.java, so when the user presses OK in the configuration acitivty, the the widgettext would be saved with the appwidgetid (Idk what appwidgetid, since the code uses AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID).

For this to work I needed this:

```
  static void saveTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId, String text) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
            prefs.putString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, text);
            prefs.commit();
        }
```

In the MyWidgetProvider class I modified the for loop like this:

```
final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        int awID = appWidgetIds[i];
        RemoteViews v = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        //v.setTextViewText(R.id.tvConfigInput, "Something");
        v.setTextViewText(R.id.tvConfigInput, loadTitlePref(context, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(awID, v);
    }
```

where I added

```
  static String loadTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            String prefix = prefs.getString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, null);
            String nothing = "empty";
            if (prefix != null) {
                return prefix;
            } else {
                return nothing;
            }
        }
```

It still doesn't work, but getting closer. I place two widgets with different texts on the home screen, then I reinstall the app. Now both widget have texts (of course, since I set it), but they have the same text, the one I selected for the 2nd widget.

Please help me.

Comment: Noone? I didn't know this was such a difficult question. I saw apps with many different user set widgets, so what should I do?

Comment: I am offering a bounty of 100 credits to anyone who tells me how to handle widgets with settings set by the user in a configuration activity.

Comment: I don't have any idea about this but just as a thought, did you try it on stock Android? I had some problems like this with sense earlier. This could be a sense specific bug just misleading you into wrong direction

Comment: I haven't tried it, because it is hard to get a stock android phone, but even if it ran smoothly on a stock android phone, I wouldn't know what to do

Comment: Use the emulator for a stock test.

Comment: I am offering 50 bounty to anyone how knows the error and posts the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the image is stored to SD card, this post might have the answer: http://www.technipages.com/android-icons-disappear-from-home-screen.html

Comment: No it is not stored on the SD card. It's in the app.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach could be mapping/saving each Id in sharedPrefs.
more info here:
[Handling multiple instances of appwidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582395/handling-multiple-instances-of-appwidget)
and here:
http://www.androidbook.com/akc/display?url=DisplayNoteIMPURL&reportId=3307&downerUserId=satya

Answer (score -1):

Re-sizing or moving the widget makes it visible after some time. To fix this, I put a default image in my imageview and it worked for me.